# how to put a button in an editText

Tags: java, android, material-design, material-components, material-components-android

I am making a chat application and I wanted to put a button in an editText to enable the sending of Media files. I don't know how to go about it.

Tried to make the vector asset in the editText clickable but it is not going

Comment: Please post what have you tried.

Comment: have you tried drawableLeft, Right?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the official [**`TextInputLayout`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) component.

You can customize the icon to use using the **`app:endIconMode="custom"`** attribute and specifying the drawable with **`app:endIconDrawable`**.

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/custom_end_icon"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_text"
    app:endIconMode="custom"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/custom_icon"
    app:endIconContentDescription="@string/custom_content_desc">

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

You can set the [`TextInputLayout#setEndIconOnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#setEndIconOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener)) method to handle the click.

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.custom_end_icon);
textInputLayout.setEndIconOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override public void onClick(View view) {
            // do something.
          }
        });
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="Type a message"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text="" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/yourImage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```